# Check if object in var is a copy ByVal or ByRef?

Tags: javascript

[Update]: I want to check (recursively) if an object copied in to a var is a ByVal copy of the original object. This means all of its children would be ByVal (deep copy), too.

I want to know if any Javascripters have ever found a way to check if a var contains a ByVal or ByRef copy. I'm afraid nothing like this exists so, I'm also interested in ideas for how to perform a check like this. A utility function would be useful for TDD.

All data types in Javascript get copied ByVal. But, when objects are copied in to a var it can store a ByRef copy of the original object - it stores a pointer in the var. But in some cases you want to copy an object ByVal either by cloning it or using a deep copy technique. Cloning gives you a shallow ByVal copy but, nested objects and arrays within it can be ByRef copies. Using a "deep copy" technique such a jQuery $.extend can overcome this to copy all nested elements ByVal. There can be different situations where you either want a true ByVal (deep copy), true ByRef or a shallow copy.

I want to be able to check a copied object and the elements within it to see if it is a true ByVal copy. Is there a good way to do this?

If you decide to write a utility function that checks for ByVal copy then you get bonus points if it recursively traverses nested elements. A good utility function could be passed an array, an object or any other data type. This is useful in case we are checking a property of an object that is a ByRef copy (a pointer).

Finally, this could be in ES2014, 2015 or 2016. I am asking for 2014 but ES2015 answers would be acceptable. Also, it would be interesting to know if any javascript frameworks have something like this built in or if a relevant package exists in the node.js world.

Comment: Everything in Javascript ByVal! Only in some cases those vals are refs. You should define a bit better what exactly you want to get out of this.

Comment: I can add some examples in the question

Comment: An *object* will always be "ByRef"; you have to explicitly clone it via some technique to make an independent copy of it. *That* should be your "test", no? If you make a clone of it, you know it's a clone.

Comment: Right. Maybe it's a matter of writing a test to check the copied obj and compare to the original obj.

Comment: No, I'm saying: *don't "test", do!* Instead of testing whether something is a copy (of what exactly…?), you clone it when you need it to have the confidence that it's a clone.

Comment: I get what you're saying.. I updated my question with details about cloning vs deep copy.

Comment: Are you perhaps really asking the following? *"Given two arbitrary variables, how can I test whether the values they hold are the same object and/or any properties of the object (recursively) refer to the same object?"*

Comment: Actually yes it's that simple.

Comment: Also, in other words: "How can I check if an object or property of an object (think recursive; nested) is really a ByRef copy?" I wish I could check if an object or any of its properties, recursively all the way deep, are a pointer. Sometimes I want them to be a pointer (ByRef)... and other times I do not (ByVal).

Comment: *That* just doesn't make a whole lot of sense/isn't possible. An object is an object, period. Variables holding it are *always* references. A reference doesn't keep track of whether or not it was assigned from one variable to another. You can only compare two given objects, not inspect their history.

Comment: You just reminded me of an important JS fact that a var is always a reference. You're right.. I wish the history could be inspected but, you helped me realize that it's always going to result in ByRef regardless if I check the original or the copy. Thinking ahead now I believe I'd have to write a test based on your idea of comparing two arbitrary vars: Recursively loop through the copy var props, attempt to update each one then validate if the original var prop was also updated. I just wonder if there's a way to check without attempting to update the entire copy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 function isCopied(val){
   return typeof val!=="object" || !!val.clonedfrom;
 }

function deepcopy(obj){
 var nobj=Object.create(Object.getPrototypeOf(obj));
 Object.assign(nobj,obj);
 for(key in nobj){
   if(typeof nobj[key]==="object"){
      nobj[key]=deepcopy(nobj[key]);
   }
 }
 nobj.clonedfrom=obj;
 return nobj;
}

console.log(
 isCopied(123),//true
 isCopied({}),//false
 isCopied(deepcopy({}))//true
);
```

Comment: I want it to work if object was cloned or copied with deep copy.. which would mean it's no longer ByRef

Comment: @bumbleB2na then simply set a property?

Comment: Thanks. This is along the lines of what I thought I wanted. I think @deceze was on to something by checking (recursively) if object A equals object B. I'm updating question now..

Comment: Ok your answer might be the best solution. I also like the thought of a utility function that handles making a deep copy. Can you think of any way to check a nested obj param to verify if the top level obj was a deep copy? Hopefully i dont have to include a ".deepcopy" param all the way down a param hierarchy. That's the extent of what I need

Comment: @BumbleB2na every nested child has already the *clonedfrom* property. If you have a reference to the parent, you can check that too